# Discord.net Bot. MusicBot capability

Tags: c#, bots, discord, discord.net

i have a music bot i am currently developing with the discord.net framework. i like it because i enjoy programming in c# the language i mainly use. but i want to expand the functionality of the bot so that  it can play music in a discord voice chat. i have done a little research onto it and i cant find any resources on how to add this functionality to my bot.

i used to have a discord bot that ran on python and right now the best idea i have is to have both the bots running under the same account so it appears as one bot that can do everything when it is in fact two. but this way just seems wrong and inneficient.

and so here i am asking for help. any resources you may have on how to make my discord.net able to play music in a voice chat would be great. and if anyone can link me some code snippets or a link to some guide would be even better

TLDR: i have a bot written in c#, can someone please link me some assets or a guide on how to add a music player to this bot

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look into user a wrapper like [Victoria](https://github.com/Yucked/Victoria/wiki) or using ffmpeg you can do something like [this](https://gist.github.com/Joe4evr/773d3ce6cc10dbea6924d59bbfa3c62a).

The general documentation from the lib itself can be found [here](https://docs.stillu.cc/guides/voice/sending-voice.html). Note, it says it's out of date but Audio hasn't changed since 1.0, so everything there should still apply.

Comment: okay so i decided i want to use ffmpeg, and i have copied the files for now just to see if i can get something working. but i don't understand how to start the AudioService from the main Program.cs

Comment: In the example, the audio module is a command module while the audio service is a service utilized by said command module. That said, it's not called from main, it's called when the command is executed. You can join the [Discord API](https://discord.gg/discord-api) server and get further help in the #dotnet_discord-net channel